# Drag & drop image doesn't work

Tags: wygwam

I'm running EE 2.7.2, Wygwam 3.2.2. Drag and drop image into the field doesn't work. After saving my entry and opening the page, I can view source and see the following:

```
<img alt="" src="data:&lt;;base64,/9j/4R5uRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAPAAABAwABAAAAQAYAAAE... .... ....</div>
```

If I insert an image by using the toolbar button and uploading an image, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Cheers

*Update* This is a bug to be addressed by P&T.

Comment: i was unaware that ckeditor (what wygwam uses) supported drag and drop... from a quick scan of the web it needs custom scripts to support this. and even then it is browser specific and not always supported...? do you have info on why this should work?

Comment: Wygwam does - updated the post.